# NameError: name 'get_transforms' is not defined

Tags: python, python-3.x, fast-ai

This code was running without any problems before I updated my python and fastai:

```
from fastai import *
from fastai.vision import *
import torch
...
tfms = get_transforms(do_flip=True,flip_vert=True,max_rotate=360,max_warp=0,max_zoom=1.1,max_lighting=0.1,p_lighting=0.5)
```

After updating the fastai to 2.1.2 and python to 3.8.5, I'm getting this error: `NameError: name 'get_transforms' is not defined`.

How can I fix it?

Comment: try importing with `from fastai import get_transforms`

Comment: `ImportError: cannot import name 'get_transforms' from 'fastai'` @Matiiss

Comment: well then either you have mistyped sth or there is another problem or there is no such function

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For Data Augmentation methods in FastAI 2 you have to use other methods names, for example:
[aug_transforms](https://docs.fast.ai/vision.augment#aug_transforms)

Answer (score 0):

I got the same question, fastai 1.0.61 could probably solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Enter this code at the very beginning and download it :

```
!pip install "torch==1.4" "torchvision==0.5.0"
```